# must appear in the group by clause in sql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a sql statement and I am trying to add order by, when I add order statement I get an error

`ERROR:  column "items.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function`

My query is.

```
WITH "has_children_cte" 
     AS (SELECT DISTINCT "parent_id" AS "item_id", 
                         1           AS "has_children" 
         FROM   "items") 
SELECT "item_category_id", 
       Count(*) AS "count" 
FROM   "items" 
       INNER JOIN "items" AS "root_item" 
               ON ( "root_item"."id" = "items"."root_id" ) 
       LEFT JOIN "item_types" 
              ON ( "items"."item_type_id" = "item_types"."id" ) 
       LEFT JOIN "item_categories" 
              ON ( "item_categories"."id" = "item_types"."item_category_id" ) 
       INNER JOIN "order_items" 
               ON ( "items"."order_item_id" = "order_items"."id" ) 
       INNER JOIN "orders" 
               ON ( "order_items"."order_id" = "orders"."id" ) 
       LEFT JOIN "has_children_cte" 
              ON ( "items"."id" = "has_children_cte"."item_id" ) 
WHERE  ( ( "items"."parent_id" IS NULL ) 
         AND ( "items"."state" != 'discarded' ) ) 
GROUP  BY "item_category_id" 
ORDER  BY "items"."id";
```

I have add the `ORDER  BY "items"."id";`

Then I get this error. When I try to add items.id into group by I got bad results.

Unfortunately I am unable to handle this error.

Comment: Why do you want to order by "items"."id"? The result of the query shows the "category_id' and a count

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ORDER BY` (logically) takes place *after* the aggregation.  And after the aggregation, `"items"."id"` is not available in each row.

So just use an aggregation function:

```
ORDER  BY MIN("items"."id")
```